# How to add calendars and contacts support to mail server

Tags: email, dovecot, calendar

I have installed Postfix, Dovecot and MySQL to set a personal mail server with virtual users stored in the database. It works great, but there are two things missing: Calendars and Contacts.

For example when you add Gmail account to your desktop / mobile app for emails you have options to sync Calendars, Contacts, Notes. I am missing the Calendars and Contacts.

Comment: In our work environment we use two web based email clients. 1) Roundcube 2) Open-xchange. Roundcube or any other web based mail clients like squirrelmail have support for contacts. Open-xchange provides calendering, contacts and much more.

Comment: I don't want to install web interface for the mail server. Can I add the functionality without it?

Comment: apparently you can (f.e. Kolab can store these data as email attachments of certain MIME type)...